# Wicket ChoiceFilteredPropertyColumn<T, Boolean> with NullValid (ConversionException)

Tags: generics, wicket, filtering

I want to create a ChoiceFilteredPropertyColumn with a Boolean as the backing model.

My problem is that I want to have a third choice in the dropdown, "Choose one". I managed adding that by overriding newDropDownChoice and setting nullValid to true (as suggested here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4412)
 but a ConversionException is thrown when choosing this value due to the backing model beeing a Boolean.

My question is; is there a way to intercept when this value is choosen? This way, i could pass a flag to where the query for the filtering is made that the current value of the Boolean is to be ignored.

(I can't change the backing model. I can't have another backing model of lets say a String, that a later use to set the value of the Boolean).

Thanks in advance!

**Edit after bernies suggestions:**

```
    @Override
    public Component getFilter(final String componentId, final FilterForm<?> form) {
    ChoiceFilter<F> filter = new ChoiceFilter<F>(componentId, getFilterModel(form), form, super.getFilterChoices(), enableAutoSubmit()) {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected DropDownChoice<F> newDropDownChoice(String id, IModel<F> model, IModel<List<? extends F>> choices, IChoiceRenderer<F> renderer) {
        DropDownChoice<F> dropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice<F>(id, model, choices, renderer) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public <C> IConverter<C> getConverter(Class<C> type) {
                super.getConverter(type);
                BooleanConverter test = new BooleanConverter() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public Boolean convertToObject(String value, Locale locale) {
                        System.out.println("I'm never printed :(");
                        return super.convertToObject(value, locale);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String convertToString(Boolean value, Locale locale) {
                        return super.convertToString(value, locale);
                    }

                };

                return (IConverter<C>) test;
            }

        };
        dropDownChoice.setNullValid(true);
        return dropDownChoice;
    }
};

IChoiceRenderer<F> renderer = getChoiceRenderer();
if (renderer != null) {
    filter.getChoice().setChoiceRenderer(renderer);
}
return filter;
}
```

Unfortunately, the convertToObject method never gets executed (only the convertToString).

I'm gonna look in to creating some custom filtering for booleans (using checkboxes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, a DropDownChoice does will not use the Converter but instead searches its list of choices (via the ChoicesRenderer) to convert to Object...

<strike>I'm not 100% sure I understand, but here's something you can try:</strike>

Override the method `public Component getFilter(final String componentId, final FilterForm<?> form)` of `ChoiceFilteredPropertyColumn` to provide your subclass of `ChoiceFilter`. This subclass should override `getConverter(Class<?>)` to return an implementation of `BooleanConverter` which accepts nulls.

Alternatively, register your own `BooleanConverter` accepting nulls globally at the `Application` level for all Booleans.

IMHO, this should be submitted as JIRA issue. Many (all?) other converters check for null inputs and return null in that case.

That said, I tried your use case on Wicket 1.5.5 and it works quite well! Try it out yourself:

#### html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form wicket:id="form">
    <table wicket:id="table"></table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Java

```
package com.wicketTest.tables;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.IClusterable;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.DataTable;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.DefaultDataTable;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.IColumn;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.PropertyColumn;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.filter.ChoiceFilter;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.filter.ChoiceFilteredPropertyColumn;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.filter.FilterForm;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.filter.FilterToolbar;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.data.table.filter.IFilterStateLocator;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.repeater.util.SortableDataProvider;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IChoiceRenderer;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;

public class ChoiceFilterPage extends WebPage {

    private ArrayList<Stuff> data;

    public ChoiceFilterPage(PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        // Provider
        data = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            data.add(new Stuff(true));
        }
        Provider provider = new Provider();

        // Form
        FilterForm<Stuff> form = new FilterForm<Stuff>("form", provider);
        add(form);

        // Columns
        List<IColumn<Stuff>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<Stuff>>();

        IModel<List<? extends Boolean>> choices = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<? extends Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<Boolean> load() {
                return Arrays.asList(Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        };
        columns.add(new ChoiceFilteredPropertyColumn<Stuff, Boolean>(Model
                .of("bool"), "boolVal", choices) {

            @Override
            public Component getFilter(String componentId, FilterForm<?> form) {
                ChoiceFilter<Boolean> filter = new ChoiceFilter<Boolean>(
                        componentId, getFilterModel(form), form,
                        getFilterChoices(), enableAutoSubmit()) {

                    @Override
                    protected DropDownChoice<Boolean> newDropDownChoice(
                            String id, IModel<Boolean> model,
                            IModel<List<? extends Boolean>> choices,
                            IChoiceRenderer<Boolean> renderer) {
                        DropDownChoice<Boolean> newDropDownChoice = super
                                .newDropDownChoice(id, model, choices, renderer);
                        newDropDownChoice.setNullValid(true);
                        return newDropDownChoice;
                    }
                };

                IChoiceRenderer<Boolean> renderer = getChoiceRenderer();
                if (renderer != null) {
                    filter.getChoice().setChoiceRenderer(renderer);
                }
                return filter;
            }
        });
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Stuff>(Model.of("string"), "stringVal"));

        DataTable<Stuff> table = new DefaultDataTable<Stuff>("table", columns,
                provider, 100);

        // Toolbar
        table.addTopToolbar(new FilterToolbar(table, form, provider));
        form.add(table);
    }

    private class Provider extends SortableDataProvider<Stuff> implements
            IFilterStateLocator<Stuff> {

        private Stuff filter = new Stuff(false);

        public Iterator<? extends Stuff> iterator(int first, int count) {
            if (filter.boolVal == null) {
                return data.subList(first, first + count).iterator();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Stuff> result = new ArrayList<Stuff>();
                for (Stuff stuff : data) {
                    if (filter.boolVal.equals(stuff.boolVal))
                        result.add(stuff);
                }
                return result.subList(first, first + count).iterator();
            }
        }

        public int size() {
            if (filter.boolVal == null) {
                return data.size();
            } else {
                int size = 0;
                for (Stuff stuff : data) {
                    if (stuff.boolVal == filter.boolVal)
                        size++;
                }
                return size;
            }
        }

        public IModel<Stuff> model(Stuff object) {
            return Model.of(object);
        }

        public Stuff getFilterState() {
            return filter;
        }

        public void setFilterState(Stuff state) {
            filter = state;
        }
    }

    private static class Stuff implements IClusterable {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public String stringVal;
        public Boolean boolVal;

        public Stuff(boolean init) {
            if (init) {
                Random random = new Random();
                stringVal = Integer.toString(random.nextInt());
                switch (random.nextInt(3)) {
                case 0:
                    boolVal = Boolean.FALSE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    boolVal = Boolean.TRUE;
                    break;
                default:
                    boolVal = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried that but couldent get it to work, maybe I've  misunderstood something.. code in edit.